# std::bad_function_call when calling std::swap in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang

I am trying to port my code from linux to windows. However with Visual Studio my code crashes with the following error:

> Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_function_call at memory location

This is my code:

```
#include <functional>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int) : m_deleter{ []() {} } {}
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo(Foo &&) = default;
    Foo & operator=(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&) = default;
    ~Foo()
    {
        m_deleter();
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> m_deleter;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo(1);
    Foo bar(2);
    std::swap(foo, bar);
}
```

It crashes when I use `std::swap`. In linux it worked flawlessly.

Weirdly enough, when I try to [compile it online](http://goo.gl/sBrNrb) via GCC it doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong and why does at work at home with Clang (3.5).

EDIT: It turns out it crashes with Visual Studio 2015 and GCC 4.9.2, but not with Clang 3.5.

Comment: @Ron Tang: If I make it default, it still crashes.

Comment: en... , Use  my linux gcc  has same error!

Comment: In linux it worked flawlessly. Which complier you use?

Comment: @Ron Tang: As stated in my question, I use Clang 3.5.

Comment: crashes with gcc 4.9.1 on ubuntu with the same exception

Comment: @fefe: Yes, I tried it too, see my edit to the question.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567287/what-causes-stdbad-function-call)

Comment: @Ron Tang: Is this (`Foo(int) : m_deleter{ []() {} } {}`) not sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction

The reason for the behavior is quite simple; `m_deleter` is unconditionally invoked in the destructor of `Foo`, even in circumstances when it isn't callable.

The straight forward implementation of `std::swap` creates a temporary to hold the intermediate result of one of the two operands, this temporary will not have a callable `m_deleter`.

<sup>**What is *std::bad_function_call*?**</sup>

[*std::bad_function_call*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call) will be thrown if you try to call a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which doesn't have a valid target to invoke.

---

---

#### Elaboration

We can reduce your *testcase* to the following, more explicit, snippet:

```
 1 #include <functional>
 2 #include <utility>
```

```
 3 struct A {
 4   A () 
 5     : _cb {[]{}}
 6   { } 
 7   
 8   A (A&& src)
 9     : _cb (std::move (src._cb))
10   { } 
11   
12   A& operator= (A&& src)
13   {
14     _cb = std::move (src._cb);
15     return *this;
16   } 
17   
18 
19   ~A () {
20     _cb ();
21   } 
22   
23   std::function<void()> _cb;
24 };
```

```
25 void swap (A& lhs, A& rhs) {
26   A temporary = std::move (lhs);
27           lhs = std::move (rhs);
28           rhs = std::move (temporary);
29 }
```

```
30 int main() {
31   A x, y;
32   swap (x, y);
33 }
```

---

<sub>**The Problem**</sub>

When leaving `swap` *temporary* will be destroyed, which in turn will try to invoke `_cb` - the problem is that `temporary._cb` has been *moved-from* on line *14*; it is no longer callable and an exception is thrown.

<sub>**The Solution**</sub>

```
~A::A () {
  if (_cb) // check if callable
    _cb (); 
}
```

Comment: So it's a bug with Clang to not crash?

Comment: @gartenriese - not Clang bug.The standard requires only that the object being moved can normally be released, as to whether to hold the original value is not required.

Comment: @gartenriese **No**, an implementation must not invalidate the object being *moved-from* - all that is said is that the object must be in a "*valid but unspecified state*". This in turns mean that when using *libc++* (the implementation of the standard library that ships with *clang), you will get an extra invocation of one of the callbacks.. but it's not an implementation bug (if anything it's yours).

Comment: I see. Well, your solution is easy and works on all three compilers, so thanks :-)

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp - I found that your code has pretty line number, how did you that? Please tell me, thanks.

Comment: @RonTang: I upvoted this answer, but the line numbers are a very bad idea, because they break that whole copy-&-paste-into-my-editor thing.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I normally don't do *line-numbering*, in this case I thought I'd make more references to individual line-numbers in the explanation of the snippet - something which didn't happen. I agree that one should, normally, not include line-numbers in their post.

Comment: @RonTang I'm a terminal user; `cat -n $FILE` or whatever floats your boat does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary object is used in `std::swap()`. When `swap()` returns, the temporary object's `m_deleter` is empty. When the temporary destructs, the `m_deleter();` throws `std::bad_function_call` as `m_deleter` has no target.

The `std::swap` on my machine (gcc4.9.1, ubuntu) is like the following:

```
template<typename _Tp>
  inline void
  swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
  noexcept(__and_<is_nothrow_move_constructible<_Tp>,
           is_nothrow_move_assignable<_Tp>>::value)
  {
    _Tp __tmp = std::move(__a);
    __a = std::move(__b);
    __b = std::move(__tmp);
  }
```

After swap, `__tmp` (of type `Foo`) holds a `std::function<void()>` object `m_deleter` with no target. The exception is thrown when it destructs and the destructor calls `m_deleter();`

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce your problem even with Visual C++ 2013, which does [not support defaulted move constructors and assignment operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#defaultedanddeleted); the same behaviour occurs with self-written functions:

```
#include <functional>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int) : m_deleter{ []() {} } {}
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo(Foo &&src) : m_deleter(std::move(src.m_deleter)) { };
    Foo & operator=(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&src) { m_deleter = std::move(src.m_deleter); return *this; }
    ~Foo()
    {
        m_deleter();
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> m_deleter;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo(1);
    Foo bar(2);
    std::swap(foo, bar);
}
```

You can then use the debugger in Visual Studio to verify what's going on. Put a breakpoint at your `std::swap` call. You will end up in the VC implementation of the function:

```
_Ty _Tmp = _Move(_Left);
_Left = _Move(_Right);
_Right = _Move(_Tmp);
```

All three of these moves will work correctly. But then the scope of the function ends, and so does the lifetime of the `_Tmp` variable. The destructor will be called on it while its `m_deleter` is empty, as you can see in the "Locals" section of the debugger GUI:

[image: Visual Studio debugger showing <code>std::swap</code> call with temporary variable whose destructor will cause a crash]

Moving means that the moved-from object has to remain in a valid state for destruction, and a state which results in calling an empty `std::function` is not valid. Others have shown you the fix in the destructor already.

Now about this...

> It turns out it crashes with Visual Studio 2015 and GCC 4.9.2, but not
>   with Clang 3.5.

Both your original code and my modification crash with Clang 3.5:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'

  what():  bad_function_call

bash: line 7: 25250 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

I tried it at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/, which according to `clang++ --version` uses `clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final 217394)`.

Comment: I use clang 3.5.0 and it did not crash.

Comment: gartenriese: What does it do if you step through it with a debugger and the exception leaves the destructor?

Comment: What do you mean? With Clang I don't get an exception.

Comment: @gartenriese: So what exactly happens your empty `std::function` is to be executed?

Comment: I don't have debugging available, sorry. It just continues the program as if std::function was not empty.